# How to normalize a position in 3d game?

Tags: machine-learning, machine-learning-model, normalization

I'm pretty new to anything and everything related to this kind of stuff, I was wondering how would I normalize the coordinates of a entity in my game for a nerual network? Would it just be the same normalizng everything else? I don't assume it'd be the same just because how big these numbers are, you'd have to have a BUNCH of date (I think?)

Edit: also I'd like to know if this would be the proper way of giving your neural network entitie's position in a 3d game?

here's an example of the coordinates, 235.56, -2332.93, -8.57

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming each coordinate axis has a fixed max and min value, and $|min_{x}| = max_{x}$, $|min_{y}| = max_{y}$, $|min_{z}| = max_{z}$, the standard normalisation procedure would be:

$$ (x,y,z) \mapsto (\frac{x}{max_{x}},\frac{y}{max_{y}},\frac{z}{max_{z}})$$

I.e. mapping the values to within the range $(-1,-1,-1)$ to $(1,1,1)$.

---

E.g. if your corrdinate system was fixed between $-100$ and $100$ for each axis, the coordinate $(10,-52,-8)$ would normalise to:

$$ (10,-52,-8) \mapsto (\frac{10}{100},\frac{-52}{100},\frac{-8}{100}) = (0.1, -0.52, -0.08)$$